Android emulator out of bounds issue cause (solution)
I'm new and can't answer a specific topic with my reputation, but I found a solution. To be precise, I found the cause of the problem, so I created this post. I experienced this problem where part of the android emulator appeared off-screen and moving the window with the keyboard didn't work (like using ALT+SPACE, M key, etc. completely useless). Visual Studio Community 2022, currently 2024, all keyboard input was routed to the emulator and the emulated Android device responded to those keystrokes, not its window itself, but then we found that the problem itself was caused by increased Windows screen DPI settings. So it was enough to go back to DPI 100 and the emulator hit the screen limits, then I lowered it because it was too high and set screen DPI back to the preferred size. Good luck!
This is the solution, not the question.
